# Measure's equality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Im selfstudying measure theory and I got stuck in a problem that seems to be really harmless but still I have no idea how to start. Any help is really appreciated.

PROBLEM:

Let u,v two measures over $(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ such that $u((a,b])=v((a,b])$ $\forall a\leq b$. Prove that $u(A)=v(A)$ $\forall A\in \mathbb{B(\mathbb{R})}$

Thanks so much! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is  fasle in general. If $u$ is the counting measure and $v=2u$ then then $u((a,b])=v((a,b])=\infty$ whenever $a <b$ but $u\{0\}=1 \neq 2=v\{0\}$.

However the result is true for finite measures: $\{A:u(A)=v(A)\}$ is  a monotone class containing finite disjoint unions of intervals of the type $(a,b]$ and Monotone Class Theorem can be used to show that $u=v$. We can push this easily to the sigma finite case.

Answer (score -2):

**Hint:**

- Do you know, or can you prove, that $\ \mathbb{B}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)\ $ is the smallest $\ \sigma$-algebra containing all sets of the form $\ \left(a, b\right]\ $ with $\ a\le b\ $?
- Can you show that the collection of sets $\ A\ $ for which $\ u\left(A\right) = v\left(A\right)\ $ must be a $\ \sigma$-algebra ?

**Update:** As [Kavi Rama Murthy's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3175456/measures-equality/3175570#3175570) shows, the answer to the second question, contrary to my too hasty presumption, is no.  Apologies for the useless suggestion.

Comment: How do you show that $\{A:u(A)=v(A)\}$ is a sigma algebra?

Comment: In fact, in general $\{A:u(A)=v(A)\}$ may fail to be a $\sigma$-algebra.  So for proofs like this we need a more advanced principle.... the "monotone class theorem" or Dynkin's "pi-lambda theorem", for example.  $\{A:u(A)=v(A)\}$ is a lambda system.