# Proving equivalent conditions about independence

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

For any σ-algebras $G_i ⊆ F, i = 1, 2, 3$, let $G_{ij} = σ(G_i, G_j)$ and
prove that the following conditions are equivalent:

(a) $P[A_3|G_{12}]$ = $P[A_3|G_2]$ for all $A_3 ∈ G_3$.

(b) $P[A_1 ∩ A_3|G_2] = P[A_1|G_2]P[A_3|G_2]$ for all $A_1 ∈ G_1$ and $A_3 ∈ G_3$.

(c) $P[A_1|G_{23}] = P[A_1|G_2]$ for all $A_1 ∈ G_1$.

I know how to prove a) implies b), but would appreciate suggestions on how to prove b) implies c) and c) implies a).

thanks!

Comment: Can you define what the notation $P(\cdot \mid \cdot)$ means in this context?

Comment: sure. $P(X|\mathcal{F}) = E[\mathbb{1}_{X}|\mathcal{F}]$, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach to proving the equivalences seems to be (a)$\iff$(b) and (b)$\iff$(c). You've already done (a)$\implies$(b), and the obvious symmetry under interchange of the indices $1$ and $3$ means that you should be able to prove (c)$\implies$(b) in the same way.  The implications I found difficult are (b)$\implies$(a) and (b)$\implies$(c), but if you can prove one of these, then again by the symmetry, you should be able to prove the other.

Here's an idea for tackling (b)$\implies$(a).  I believe it's possible to show that if (b) holds then
$$
E\left[\mathbb{1}_AP\left[A_3\left|G_{12}\right.\right]\right]= E\left[ \mathbb{1}_A  P\left[A_3\left|G_2\right.\right]\right]
$$
for all $\ A\in G_1\cup G_2\ $, and $\ A_3\in G_3\ $. Now if you can show that the set of *all* $\ A\ $ for which this equation holds is a $\sigma$-algebra, then since that $\sigma$-algebra contains $\ G_1\cup G_2\ $, it must contain $\ G_{12}\ $, and so the equation will hold for all $\ A\in G_{12}\ $. Then, since $\ P\left[A_3\left|G_{12}\right.\right]\ $ and $\ P\left[A_3\left|G_2\right.\right]\ $ are both $\ G_{12}$-measurable, (a) will follow from the uniqueness  of the Radon-Nikodym derivative.

**Derivation of above equation**

For all $\ A_1\in G_1\ $ and $\ A_3\in G_3\ $ we have
\begin{align}
P\left[A_1\cap A_3\left|G_2\right.\right]&=E\left[P\left(A_1\cap A_3\left|G_{12}\right.\right] \left|G_2 \right.\right]\ \text{because } G_2\subseteq G_{12}\\
&=E\left[\mathbb{1}_{A_1}P\left[A_3\left|G_{12}\right.\right] \left|G_2 \right.\right]\ \text{because } A_1\in G_{12}\ ,
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
P\left[ A_1\left|G_2\right.\right] P\left[A_3\left|G_2\right.\right]&=E\left[\mathbb{1}_{A_1}  \left|G_2 \right.\right] P\left[A_3\left|G_2\right.\right]\\
&= E\left[\mathbb{1}_{A_1}P\left(A_3\left|G_2\right.\right) \left|G_2 \right.\right]
\end{align}
because $\ P\left(A_3\left|G_2\right.\right)\ $ is $\ G_2$-measurable.  Thus, if (b) holds, we get
$$
E\left[\mathbb{1}_{A_1}P\left[A_3\left|G_{12}\right.\right] \left|G_2 \right.\right]= E\left[\mathbb{1}_{A_1}P\left(A_3\left|G_2\right.\right) \left|G_2 \right.\right]
$$
for all $\ A_1\in G_1\ $ and $\ A_3\in G_3\ $.  Putting $\ A_1=\Omega\ $, the sure event, in this equation, and multiplying by $\ \mathbb{1}_{A_2}\ $ for any $\ A_2\in  G_2\ $, we have
\begin{align}
E\left[\mathbb{1}_{A_2}P\left[A_3\left|G_{12}\right.\right] \left|G_2 \right.\right]&= \mathbb{1}_{A_2} E\left[P\left[A_3\left|G_{12}\right.\right] \left|G_2 \right.\right]\ \text{because } A_2\in G_2\\
&= \mathbb{1}_{A_2} E\left[P\left[A_3\left|G_2\right.\right] \left|G_2 \right.\right]\\
&= E\left[ \mathbb{1}_{A_2}  P\left[A_3\left|G_2\right.\right] \left|G_2 \right.\right]\ \text{because } A_2\in G_2\ .
\end{align}
Thus, if (b) holds we can conclude that
$$
E\left[\mathbb{1}_AP\left[A_3\left|G_{12}\right.\right] \left|G_2 \right.\right]= E\left[ \mathbb{1}_A  P\left[A_3\left|G_2\right.\right] \left|G_2 \right.\right]
$$
for all $\ A\in G_1\cup G_2\ $, and $\ A_3\in G_3\ $, and, by taking expectations of both sides, that
$$
E\left[\mathbb{1}_AP\left[A_3\left|G_{12}\right.\right]\right]= E\left[ \mathbb{1}_A  P\left[A_3\left|G_2\right.\right]\right]
$$
for all $\ A\in G_1\cup G_2\ $, and $\ A_3\in G_3\ $.

Comment: thanks! could you please elaborate how might one show the given statement about expectations holds if b) is true?

Comment: I've added my derivation. It uses similar ideas to those I used to get (a)$\implies$(b).

Comment: Let $S$ be the set of $A$s satisfying the relation. Then $G_{12} \subset S,$ whch is enough for the argument, although I don't know if $S$ is a sigma-alg. or not. First, $S$ is a $\lambda$-system: $1_{A^c} = 1_{\Omega} - 1_A$, and for disjoint $A_i, 1_{\cup A_i} = \sum 1_{A_i},$ and then use bounded convergence. Next note that your argument works for $A \in T:=\{A_1 \cap A_2 : A_1 \in G_1, A_2 \in G_2\}$ (don't set $A_1 = \Omega$, and note that $1_{A_1 \cap A_2} =1_{A_1} 1_{A_2}$). $T$ is clearly a $\pi$-system, so $\sigma(T) = G_{12} \subset S$ by the $\pi-\lambda$ thm.

Comment: Thanks. Having been [caught out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3175456/measures-equality/3175466#3175466) on this type of argument before, I'm glad to see that most of this one can be used (if not necessarily in the way I'd suggested) to obtain the OP's desired result.